# Any image library available on Linux to get the location of cliped small image in original image?

Tags: linux, image-processing

Supposing that i have a small image named `sub-imag.png` which is clipped from a large image  named `imag.png`, and later, i want to get the `sub-imag.png`'s left-top location in `imag.png`.

Is there any image library on linux can do this kind of work?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at next libraries:

- [VlFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/)
- [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)

But I believe the best match for your needs would be [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php) with its [compare()](http://imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/) function, because of its simplicity.